# How to calculate the limit at 0 of trigonometric functions without using L’hopital’

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(\ln(1+x^2)) \arccos(\ln(1+x^2))}{\tan(\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}) (1+x^2)^{1/2}} $$

I have gotten as far as setting $u = 1 + x^2$, but I get stuck because I’m not sure what to do next.

Comment: Hint: try setting $u=\ln(1+x^2)$ instead.

Comment: In general, the only 3 ways that I can think of are L'Hopital's Rule, Taylor Series, or Geometry.  I would exclude Geometry here as too complex.  Please give **background**:  that is what theorems, or previously solved problems from your book/class do you think **might** be pertinent here.

Comment: parentheses at the denominator are not clear

Comment: @BarryCipra +1, nice, I overlooked making a clever substitution.

Comment: @user, agreed, but I'm guessing the cube root is *inside* the logarithm (and thus can be taken outside as a $1/3$).

Comment: I would crudely say $\ln(1+x^2)\approx x^2$ and so $1+x^2\approx 1$ and $\arccos(\ln(1+x^2))\approx \frac{\pi}2$ and $\sin(y) \approx \tan(y) \approx y$ and say this is not far from $\frac{(x^2)^2\frac{\pi}2 }{(x^2)^{1/3}}$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{\sin^2(\ln(1+x^2)) \arccos(\ln(1+x^2))}{\tan(\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}) (1+x^2)^{1/2}}=$$

$$\frac{\sin^2(\ln(1+x^2))}{\ln^2(1+x^2)}\frac{\arccos(\ln(1+x^2))}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}}{\tan(\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}) }\frac{\ln^2(1+x^2)}{\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}} \to 0$$

indeed

- $\frac{\sin^2(\ln(1+x^2))}{\ln^2(1+x^2)}\to 1$
- $\frac{\arccos(\ln(1+x^2))}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\to\frac \pi 2$
- $\frac{\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}}{\tan(\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}) }\to 1$
- $\frac{\ln^2(1+x^2)}{\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}}=\frac{\ln^2(1+x^2)}{(x^2)^2}\frac{(x^2)^\frac13}{\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3}}
     x^{\frac43} \to 0$

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(\ln(1+x^2)) \arccos(\ln(1+x^2))}{\tan(\ln(1+x^2)^{1/3} )(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$$
As suggested in the comments by  @Barry Cipra substitute $u=\ln (1+x^2)$
$$L=\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(u) \arccos(u)}{\tan(u^{1/3}) e^{u/2}}$$
$$L=\lim_{u \to 0} \dfrac{\sin^2(u)}{u^2} \dfrac {(u^{1/3} )}{\tan(u^{1/3})}\arccos(u) (u^{5/3} e^{-u/2})$$
Then use:
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}u=1$$
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \arccos(u)=\dfrac {\pi}2$$
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\tan u}u=1$$
Finally:
$$\implies L=1\times 1 \times \dfrac {\pi}2 \times 0=0$$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @marco

Comment: The exoression used here is different from the one in the question. @marco could you please give the exact expression.

Comment: Someone has eited the question since I have answered @user

Comment: @Aryadeva It's fine, maybe it is the correct expression. We need that marco gives a clarification about that.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when posting and the edited version is the correct expression.

Comment: @marco No problem I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome @marco